# Can be true ByRef achieved in VBA?

Tags: vba, pass-by-reference

After recent tests with PDF printer I found out that VBA's `ByRef` is not truly passing reference to variable as expected: Values of asychnronously changed variables are never updated when passed by reference.

In the following simplified example, **`ByRef Variable` parameter will never change its value**:

```
'--- definition ---

Private Sub WaitUntilEqual(ByRef Variable As Variant, ByVal Value As Variant)
    Dim PollingInterval as Integer = 200
    Do While Variable <> Value 
        TimeSpent = TimeSpent + PollingInterval
        Sleep PollingInterval
    Loop
End Sub

'--- usage (initializations omitted) ---

PdfCreator.cPrint "filename1"
PdfCreator.cPrint "filename2"
PdfCreator.cPrint "filename3"
'at this point, PdfCreator.cCountOfPrintjobs is 0 and needs few seconds to raise to 3
WaitUntilEqual PdfCreator.cCountOfPrintjobs, 3  'this will stick forever - it shouldn't
```

Is this a VBA limitation? Can this be circumvented?

I need this method 3-4 times (and it also includes extra features like timeout etc...) so I do not want to repeat entire wait loop via copy-paste.

Comment: What does `PdfCreator.cCountOfPrintjobs` return? It would need to be an object with a default property returning the current count in order for what you have to work. If it returns a numeric primitive like integer then your just passing a new integer containing a copy of the `cCountOfPrintjobs` value (at call time) to the sub, this will never change as its unbound from the object. You could pass in `PdfCreator`, then modify the loop to check the property in realtime; `while Variable.cCountOfPrintjobs <> Value `

Comment: `PdfCreator.cCountOfPrintjobs` is probably a `Get Property` method, so what you are doing is in fact comparing a copy of a value returned by this method. I don't believe you can reference the property itself in VBA. However, you could use the `CallByName` function to avoid multiple loops

Comment: Based on your insights, I resolved the problem by creating two universal parts of waiting loop: initilization (reads timeout from config, inits counters) and loop body (waits some time, tests and handles timeout). Each applied wait loop uses these two subroutines but the check for main condition is directly in the loop, not inside these subroutines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure how much of this applies to VBA, but MSDN says that the calling code *can* force `ByVal` call if the output value does not have an "address", i.e. is not a variable, but the result of an evaluation, or function call, or an  immediate constant etc.

Suppose `cCountOfPrintjobs` is a `Property Get` of the object `PdfCreator`. That means that actually there's a function that checks its internals of the objects, figures out how many print jobs there are, and returns that value. That value is returned "on stack", it doesn't have a fixed "address" to be polled by your code. To avoid reading invalid/unset memory areas, VBA will change the call to `ByVal`, so your code hangs, because there's nothing to change the argument value.

*Later edit*

[z̫͋](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3484251/z) already gave the answer in comment section...

Comment: VBA will make a copy of the value if it is not an `lvalue`, and you will get a reference to that instead. lvalue just means an expression which can be byref.... property get is really a disguised function call not a variable, so it cannot be byref.

Comment: @Ben: Exactly. And I suspect that the copy will be created in the function/sub argument list. :-) Here's the link that I mentioned in my post: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ddck1z30.aspx (check "Determination of the Passing Mechanism") -- it is for VB rather than VBA though.

Comment: @CST-Link [here's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156838.aspx) the VBA specification: `If [...] the parameter is ByRef and the mapped argument’s expression is classified as a value, function, property or unbound member, a local variable is defined with procedure extent within the procedure being invoked with the same name value and declared type as the parameter, and has its value assigned as follows:[...]`

Comment: @z̫͋: Thanks for taking the pains of finding the right documentation for the matter. :-)